# Triggering Events on Siblings Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, dom-events

I have a form and in that from I do a foreach over each field and pass the fields into their own components. I would like to trigger an event that propagates to all sibling fields triggered from a field component.

I know that I can do this from the field component
`this.dispatch('activeField', this.field);`

And then form the Form component
`this.broadcast('activeField', this.field);`

It seems like there should be a way of doing this without the overhead of involving the parent. I'm using Vue 1.0 and this example is just to demonstrate an issue I'm running into.
This is pseudo code so there very well could be typos.

Comment: Involve the parent. Siblings should not know about each other.

Answer (score 3):

The "full-blown" methodology is to use Vuex or another shared state flux provider.  However, that isn't absolutely necessary.

You can also utilize a standalone Vue instance as an event bus to emit a message from the field component and receive it in the form component.

eventBusWrapper.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const EventBus = new Vue()
export default {
    EventBus
}
```

Field Component

```
import EventBus from './eventBusWrapper'
EventBus.$emit('activeField', this.field)
```

Form Component

```
import EventBus from './eventBusWrapper'
EventBus.$on('activeField', (field) => {
    console.log(field)
});
```

Comment: This is clever but my lead would have a cow. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ShawnPivonka happy to help but I genuinely don't understand your lead's objection. What is their concern?

Comment: It's not consistent behavior with the rest of the code base.

Comment: @ShawnPivonka I'm not sure I follow and without seeing a more concrete example of the current consistent behavior, I'm afraid I can't offer you a more useful answer.  You have three options: use the parent to communicate to the siblings (but you don't want to do that), use Vuex (which is overkill), or use a small event bus like my answer (which your lead wouldn't like).  I don't think you have too many other options :).